# Ajax not submitting $_Post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this section of code that is suppose to get the Values of the input fields and then add them to the database. The collection of the values works correctly and the insert into the database works correctly, I am having issue with the data posting. I have narrowed it down to the data: and $__POST area and im not sure what I have done wrong.

JS Script

```
$("#save_groups").click( function() {

var ids = [];

$.each($('input'), function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    //Put ID in array.
    ids.push(id);
    console.log('IDs'+ids);
});

$.ajax({        

       type: "POST",
       url: "inc/insert.php",
       data: {grouparray: ids },
       success: function() {
            $("#saved").fadeOut('slow');   
                    console.log('Success on ' + ids);
       }
    }); 


});
```

PHP Section

```
<?php
include ('connect.php');

$grouparray = $_POST['grouparray'];

$user_ID = '9';

$sql = "INSERT INTO wp_fb_manager (user_id, group_id) VALUES ($user_ID, $grouparray)";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysql_error();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an array trough an ajax call.

First, use something like:

```
var idString = JSON.stringify(ids);
```

And use it: `data: {grouparray: idString },`

On the PHP side:

```
$array = json_decode($_POST['grouparray']);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: When doing this it says that ids is not defined, i replaced   var ids = []; with var idString = JSON.stringify(ids);

Comment: You should use that `var isString ... ` after `$.each ...`

Comment: Made the modifications and still having the same issues, I can see the data in the console log and can make the variables equal something in the php and get it to submit but it is not sending the data to the PHP file

Comment: you can too send arrays and even arrays of objects...jQuery will urlencode it internally. Answer is not true